# Python Fixed Length Packet

Tags: python, sockets, binary

I am trying to build a fixed length packet in python for an ATSC PSIP generator.  This is probably very simple but so far I can't seem to get it to work.  I am trying to build a packet with fields similar to the following:

```
table_id = 0xCB
syntax = 0b1
reserved = 0b11
table_ext = 0xFF
```

the end goal would be the following in binary

```
'1100101111111111111'
```

I have tried a dozen different things and can't get the results I would expect.
I am going to send this via sockets so I believe it needs to end up in a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`struct` module](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) to build binary strings from arbitrary layouts.

That can only generate byte-aligned structures, but you'll need to be byte aligned to send on the network socket anyway.

EDIT:

So the format you're generating really does have non-aligned bits 8-1-1-2-12-16 etc.

In order to send on a socket you'll need to be byte aligned, but I guess that the protocol handles that some how. (maybe with padding bits somewhere?)

My new suggestion would be to build up a bit string, then chop it up into 8-bit blocks and convert from there:

```
input_binary_string = "110010111111111111101010" ## must be a multiple of 8
out = []
while len(input_binary_string) >= 8:
    byte = input_binary_string[:8]
    input_binary_string = input_binary_string[8:]
    b = int(byte,2)
    c = chr(b)
    out.append(c)
## Better not have a bits left over
assert len(input_binary_string) == 0
outString = "".join(out)

print [ ord(c) for c in out ]
```

Comment: Struct can't seem to handle adding just one bit... am I missing something?

Comment: the smallest unit of data that can be used with the struct module and with sockets is 1 byte

Comment: I assume then that means the struct module doesn't help me.

Comment: When you send on a socket you're going to need byte aligned blocks.
All protocols I've ever seen are byte-aligned - are you sure ATSC PSIP isn't?

Comment: I checked out ATSC PSIP (http://www.atsc.org/standards/a_65cr1_with_amend_1.pdf) and it looks like the data structures you need to send around are all byte aligned blocks - its just that, in each block, specific bits can correspond to different fields. so, struct won't get you 100% of the way. For a particular byte within a block that is split into, say, 3 fields, you would have to construct the value of that byte using standard bit-wise operations (http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#bit-string-operations-on-integer-types) and then set that byte in the block using the struct module.

Comment: Thanks Douglas!  I started working on a similar approach but your method is much cleaner.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Construct (http://construct.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is a parser and builder for binary data. It does look to be ideal for this application, as you can define things from bits and bytes. It also looks to have useful features like handling conditional situations as well as easily checking for terminators and the like.

I've spent years using a system for complicated packet creation and parsing that didn't have some of the features that Construct has, so unless there's something particularly odd either in the protocol, it looks like Construct will handle it.